# hwmon device (lm75) not getting detected

Tags: linux, driver, kernel-module, i2c

I have a board with TMP75 temp sensor on an i2c bus, which is handled by lm75 driver. It's at the address 0x4a. 
I'm loading the driver (linux) and it's getting loaded but it is not detecting the device.

In the /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/lm75/ , I see only following files/folder : 
`bind` `module` `uevent` `unbind`.

I don't see any other entry where possibly the temp_input etc. device attributes are present. Not sure how do I debug this further..

I can see the driver loaded in `lsmod`

`/sys/bus/i2c/devices/` doesn't show the device to be bound.

Update:
I put prints in the `probe` to see if that's getting called. I don't see those prints.

Comment: Hint: instead of putting `printf()` here and there, use `initcall_debug` in the kernel command line.

Comment: How do you think it can get be enumerated? Yes, ether thru ACPI, or DT, or hard coded platform code (aka board files). Another way is to do this manually via *bind* interface under sysfs.